# Netsuite - CSV Import of Invoices

Tags: netsuite, csv-import

I'm using NetSuite's CSV import to import invoices into the system.

The problem is that we tried to import transactions that should have been made from Sales Orders, with column Created From in CSV and wanted to map it to Created From Field. But because field Created From is disabled in Netsuite and cant be added to custom form of invoice, we don't have an option to map the data to that field.

Is there a workaround for this problem except to make a map/reduce script that would do record.transform() on said sales order records?

Comment: You need to transform  the saleOrder to  ItemFullfilment first  then you  can  transform your saleOrder to Invoice.

Comment: @wozzarvl My clients don't use Item Fullfilment records so this won't be needed.